# I want to remotely connect Sharepoint server through powershell whose database is on different machine

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server

My SharePoint server is on machine M1 and its database is on machine M2. 
I want to connect and run SharePoint PowerShell command from altogether different machine M3 remotely with user U1.

Is it possible ?
What all permissions required for user U1 to connect and run SharePoint server remotely from machine M3 ? Adding user U1 as "Farm Account" which is service account is not helpful.

Please suggest solutions

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible, Please follow the steps below.

**On the client machine (the management server):**

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer * -Force
Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Credssp\PolicyDefaults\AllowFreshCredentials -Name WSMan -Value WSMAN/*
Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Credssp\PolicyDefaults\AllowFreshCredentialsDomain -Name WSMan -Value WSMAN/*
```

**On the SharePoint server:**

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server -Force
```

Afterwards it is possible to connect to the server using PowerShell from your management server, using the following cmdlet:

```
Enter-PSSession SPServer -Authentication CredSSP -Credential "DOMAIN\username"
```

Add the SharePoint PowerShell SnapIn

```
Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

To see if it works, run a simple SharePoint cmdlet:

```
Get-SPSite
```

[PowerShell Remoting for SharePoint](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/powershell-remoting-for-sharepoint)

Comment: Are you sure ? as SharePoint database is on different machine and sharepoint server is also on different machine altogether. Now I want to connect it remotely via PowerShell through from my machine. What permissions required for user ?

Comment: yes, it is really doesn't matter, if database is on different server or not....as far as they are single farm( multiple servers no issue)...you able to connect it. i think you need shelladmin rights to runt he powershell against

Answer (score 0):

The best approach in time and effort is used CSOM PowerShell commands or PnP PowerShell commands. This commands are different from the SharePoint Command PowerShell but you can run lot of administration commands and much more.