# New-SPSite User cannot be found - SharePoint 2013 Remote PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, spsite

I am using Remote PowerShell Session to create SharePoint Site. **The client computer is not part of AD forest.**

I have used the following PowerShell commands to enter into the remote session.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "SPServerName" -Credential $cred
Enter-PSSession $session
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

and following commands to create SharePoint Site

```
$w = Get-SPWebApplication http://SPServerName:8000/

New-SPSite http://sp.test.com -OwnerAlias "ad\spuser" -HostHeaderWebApplication $w -Name "Test Site"
```

And I am getting the following error

> New-SPSite : User cannot be found.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + New-SPSite http://sp.test.com -OwnerAlias "ad\spuser" -HostH ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletNewSite:SPCmdletNewSite) [New-SPSite], SPException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSite

However, I am able to create SharePoint Site successfully from within SharePoint server using same PowerShell commands.

Comment: check this out http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145953/i-want-to-remotely-connect-sharepoint-server-through-powershell-whose-database-i

Answer (score 2):

You can follow below article to configure remote PowerShell on SharePoint Server.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/anneste/2014/09/17/how-to-enable-remote-powershell-for-sharepoint-2013-for-non-administrators/

Since you are doing remote PowerShell you need to make sure PowerShell Process is running under SharePoint Farm Admin or SharePoint Managed Account.